# Show by IBP that $I_n= \int^{\pi/2}_0(\cos\theta)^nd\theta=\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have that $I_n= \int^{\pi/2}_0(\cos\theta)^nd\theta$ for $n=1,2,...$

I need to show that by IBP that $I_n=\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$

My attempt:

$I_n=\int^{\pi/2}_0(\cos\theta)^n d\theta=$

Transformation: $\cos\theta=u \Rightarrow du=-\sin\theta d\theta, \theta=\pi/2\Rightarrow u=0, \theta=0 \Rightarrow u=1$

$\Rightarrow I_n= \int^1_0\frac{u^n }{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$

IBP: $u^n=t \Rightarrow nu^{n-1}=dt, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=dv \Rightarrow \arcsin(u)=v$

So, the integral is equal to:

$u^n\arcsin(u)\Big|^1_0-\int^1_0\arcsin(u)nu^{n-1}du=\pi/2-\int^1_0\arcsin(u)nu^{n-1}du$

Evalutating $\int^1_0\arcsin(u)nu^{n-1}du$:

IBP: $nu^{n-1}=t\Rightarrow n(n-1)u^{n-2}dn=dt, dv=\arcsin(u)du, \Rightarrow v=u\arcsin(u)+\sqrt{1-u^2}$

So 
$$\int^1_0\arcsin(u)nu^{n-1}du=nu^{n-1}(\arcsin(u)-\sqrt{1-u^2})\Big|^1_0-\int^1_0\left(u\arcsin(u)+\sqrt{1-u^2})(n(n-1)u^{n-2}\right)du=n(\pi/2)-n^2(n-1)\int^1_0\arcsin(u)u^{n-2}+n(n-1)\int^1_0u^{n-2}\sqrt{1-u^2}$$

Well, at this point I feel lost. I don't quite seem how i'm supposed to get

$$\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}=\frac{n-1}{n}\int^{pi/2}_0(\cos\theta)^{n-2}d\theta$$

From the above integral. Could anyone please say where i'm going wrong, or what could I do to get it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use and make IPP of $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)^{n+1}d\theta = \int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(\theta)^{n}\cos(\theta)d\theta $$ knowing that $\sin'=cos$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
use directly  integration by parts, setting

$$\begin{cases}u=\cos^{n-1}\theta,\\
\mathrm dv =\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta,
\end{cases} \quad\text{ whence }\quad\begin{cases}\mathrm du=-(n-1)\cos^{n-2}\theta\sin\theta\,\mathrm d\theta,\\
v =\sin\theta.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

IBP
$$\begin{align}
I_n= &\int^{\pi/2}_0\cos^n\theta d\theta
= \int^{\pi/2}_0 \cos^{(n-1)}\theta \>d(\sin\theta)\\
= &\cos^{(n-1)}\theta \>\sin\theta|^{\pi/2}_0 
+(n-1)\int^{\pi/2}_0 \cos^{(n-2)}\theta sin^2\theta d\theta
\\
= & (n-1)\int^{\pi/2}_0 \cos^{(n-2)}\theta d\theta
-(n-1)\int^{\pi/2}_0 \cos^{n}\theta d\theta \\
=& (n-1 I_{n-1} -(n-1 )I_n\\
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$I_n =\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$$