# show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}nI^2_n=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is a continuation of the problem in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643256/show-by-ibp-that-i-n-int-pi-2-0-cos-thetand-theta-fracn-1ni-n-2#3643287)

I was asked to show that $I_{2n}I_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{\pi}{2}$ and I did.

I am asked to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}nI^2_n=\frac{\pi}{2}$

What i tried so far:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}nI^2_n=n\left(\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}\right)^2$$=n\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2\left(\frac{n-3}{n-2}\right)^2I_{n-4}$

So, if n is even, the upper product would equal to:

$$\frac{n\left((n-1)(n-3)(n-5)...1\right)^2}{n^2\left((n-2)(n-4)...2\right)^2}I_0=...$$

I'm not sure how would this equal to $\pi/2$.

I also tried evaluating it with integrals, but it did not get me anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Comment: An idea : you have $I_{2n+1}\leq I_{2n}\leq I_{2n-1}$. Multiply this by $I_{2n}$, and then note that $I_{2n}\leq I_{2n-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lemma: Monotoniticy of $I_n$

To prove: $I_{n+1} \leq I_{n}$ for all $n$.

Thanks to a hint of the commenter, we first want to prove that $I_n$ is monotonically decreasing. Well, this is actually fairly easy if we observe a simple fact about $\cos(\theta)$ in the range $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. We know that since $0 \leq \cos(\theta) \leq 1$ in this range then for all $n$, $\cos^{n + 1}(\theta) \leq \cos^{n}(\theta)$. This is simply because multiplying by a fraction between $0$ and $1$ always decreases a number.

Now, looking at the definition of $I$, we know that the function being integrated is a power of the cosine function in the given range. Since the cosine has been shown to be non-increasing as the power increases at all points in the range, then the area under that cosine, i.e. the integral, must also decrease. Proving our lemma.

### Lemma: Limit of $I^2_n$ is $0$

I'll let you prove this.

### Proof

With our lemma, and with a little suggestion from a commenter, we can easily prove this. The strategy to show the limit is to sandwich the function we want to limit between two known functions that have limits. So let's do that. First, let's return to what you've already shown:

$I_{2n}I_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{\pi}{2}$

What you now need to show is:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}nI^2_n=\frac{\pi}{2}$

We'll define two "slices of bread" for our sandwich to make the limit work. We'll define an upper slice $U(n)$ and a lower slice $L(n)$ and show that our function is bound between them. First though, we define the slices and show that they both limit to the same term. Let $U(n) = 2nI_{2n}I_{2n-1}$ and let $L(n) = 2nI_{2n}I_{2n+1}$

$\lim_{n\to \infty}L(n) = \lim_{n\to \infty}2nI_{2n}I_{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n}{2n+1}\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

This is obtained by simply multiplying the identity proved in the last question and applying a limit both sides. We also have a slight variation on this:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}U(n) = \lim_{n\to \infty}2nI_{2n}I_{2n-1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n}{2n}\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Great. So now our strategy is to sandwich between these two functions, which both limit to the same value as we've shown. So, back to the result we want to prove:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}nI^2_n=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Well, if we can show that the even subsequence for $n = 2, 4, 6, \dots$ of the LHS limit to the RHS and if we show that the odd subsequence for $n = 1, 3, 5, \dots$ limits to the RHS, then we have shown the limit exists. Let's start with the even subsequence. We want to show:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}2nI^2_{2n}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Now, our lemma of monotonicity of $I_n$ gives us:

$I_{2n + 1} \leq I_{2n} \leq I_{2n - 1}$

So, taking a hint from the comments, we can multiply both sides by the middle, which is always positive being an area under a curve, to get:

$I_{2n}I_{2n + 1} \leq I^2_{2n} \leq I_{2n}I_{2n - 1}$

And so, multiplying both sides by $2n$, which is OK because $n$ is positive, we have:

$2nI_{2n}I_{2n + 1} \leq 2nI^2_{2n} \leq 2nI_{2n}I_{2n - 1}$

We notice that the left and right sides are the slices of bread for our sandwich, whose limits we've already proved above:

$L(n) \leq 2nI^2_{2n} \leq U(n)$

This immediately proves via the sandwich theorem that the sequence of even values of $n = 2, 4, 6, \dots$ limits as we need. So all that remains to show is that the odd values of $n$ limit to the same amount. Again we invoke the sandwich theorem, and our monotonicity of $I_n$. By monotonicity, we have:

$I_{2n + 2} \leq I_{2n + 1} \leq I_{2n}$.

So, because $I$ is always a positive area under a curve, and $n$ is positive:

$(2n + 1)I^2_{2n + 2} \leq (2n + 1)I^2_{2n + 1} \leq (2n + 1)I^2_{2n}$.

Rearranging:

$(2n + 2)I^2_{2n + 2} - I^2_{2n + 2} \leq (2n + 1)I^2_{2n + 1} \leq (2n)I^2_{2n} + I^2_{2n}$.

Since $I^2_n$ limits to $0$, by the above lemma, then both extremities of this inequality chain limit to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and by the sandwich theorem all is solved.

Comment: actually this is a very well-explaining answer, I get such answers rarely, so thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Denoting $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ W_{n}=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin^{n}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} $, (We can prove that $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ W_{n}=I_{n} $ by substituting $ x=\frac{\pi}{2}-y $).

We have : \begin{aligned} \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ W_{n+1}&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin{x}\sin^{n}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} \\ &=\left[-\cos{x}\sin^{n}{x}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+n\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos^{2}{x}\sin^{n-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ &=n\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left(1-\sin^{2}{x}\right)\sin^{n-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ W_{n+1}&=n\left(W_{n-1}-W_{n+1}\right)\\ \iff \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ W_{n+1}&=\displaystyle\frac{n}{n+1}W_{n-1} \end{aligned}

And since $ \left(W_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ is positive and decreasing, we have that : $$ \left(\forall n\geq 2\right),\ W_{n+1}\leq W_{n}\leq W_{n-1}\iff \displaystyle\frac{n}{n+1}\leq\displaystyle\frac{W_{n}}{W_{n-1}}\leq 1 $$

Thus $ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{W_{n}}{W_{n-1}}}=1 \cdot $

We can easily verify that the sequence $ \left(y_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ defined as following $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ y_{n}=\left(n+1\right)W_{n}W_{n+1} $ is a constant sequence. (Using the recurrence relation that we got from the integration by parts to express $ W_{n+1} $ in terms of $ W_{n-1} $ will solve the problem)

Hence $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ y_{n}=y_{0}=W_{0}W_{1}=\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot $

Now that we've got all the necessary tools, we can prove that $ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\sqrt{n}W_{n}}=\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}} : $ \begin{aligned} \displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\sqrt{n}W_{n}} &=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\sqrt{y_{n-1}}\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{W_{n}}{W_{n-1}}}}\\ &=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{W_{n}}{W_{n-1}}}}\\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\sqrt{n}W_{n}}&=\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}} \end{aligned}

Comment: but the integral in the question is $\int^{\pi/2}_0\cos^n(x)dx$

Comment: @Marina Using the substitution $ x=\frac{\pi}{2}-y $, we have, for every integer $ n $ the following : $$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos^{n}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin^{n}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y} $$

If you want me to change all sines to cosines in my answer, I'll do it. Nothing will change.